# How I can optimize this subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery, query-optimization

I write a query with joins and subquery. Its execution takes 2 minutes. I can't optimize it how can I do? Any suggestion?

```
select oli.*,oli2.* from order o
LEFT JOIN order_line_item oli ON oli.order_id = o.id
LEFT JOIN order_line_item oli2 ON oli2.id 
= (SELECT oli3.id FROM order_line_item oli3
WHERE oli3.order_id = o.id
AND oli.code = oli3.alternative
GROUP BY oli3.code, o.id
LIMIT 1)  WHERE o.store_id != 100 GROUP BY oli.code, oli2.code, o.id
```

My subquery works correctly but it takes too much time. Actually, it finds the alternative products. How can I optimize my subquery?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` output for all tables involved in your query.

Comment: Also, is it necessary to select `*`? If you don't need all the columns, there may be improvements available based on what we learn from your table structure (above comment) and from what columns you do need.

Comment: That smells like an invalid use of `GROUP BY` because of the `*`.

Comment: Please explain in English what the query is trying to do.  (The query is too complex for me to understand.  I think there might be a simpler way to approach it.)

Comment: Think there is an order. This order has 11 items(products) which stored in order line items table. One of products is finished and the system has an alternative product for this finished product. I have to calculate the amount of products given, and amount of alternative products given to customer seperately. A product's alternated_to column is assigned to alternative product's code. So I used oli.code = oli3.alternative. It works correct but my subquery is take too much time @RickJames

Comment: We need `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see what indexes you have and their datatypes.

Comment: I added show create table @RickJames

Answer (score 0):

The subquery in `oli2 ON` is what's causing the slowness since it needs to be executed for every row. It could be simplified to this:

```
SELECT
    oli.*,
    oli2.* 
FROM order o

LEFT JOIN order_line_item oli 
ON oli.order_id = o.id

LEFT JOIN order_line_item oli2 
ON (
    o.id = oli2.order_id
    AND 
    oli.code = oli2.alternative
)

WHERE o.store_id != 100 

GROUP BY oli.code, oli2.code, o.id
```

Comment: Thank you but it is still slow

Answer (score 0):

The index on `code` is probably useless because of "prefixing".  (Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to confirm.`)

The "767 limit in 5.6" has multiple workarounds; the "191 fix" is probably the worst for your situation.  My [*Limits blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes) lists your fix and 4 others:

- Upgrade to 5.7.7 for 3072 byte limit -- your cloud may not provide this;
- Change 255 to 191 on the VARCHAR -- you lose any values longer than 191 characters (unlikely?);
- `ALTER .. CONVERT TO utf8` -- you lose Emoji and some of Chinese;
- (your current fix) Use a "prefix" index -- you lose some of the performance benefits.
- Stay with 5.6/5.5/10.1 but perform 4 steps to raise the limit to 3072 bytes (details in the blog).

Be sure to change both `code` and `alternative`.  If this recommendation does not suffice, I'll dig deeper.